# Time Zone JS, need help with formatting

Tags: javascript

This code displays times zones vertically. I would like to display them horizontally but with appropriate spacing. I want to replace  the 'br' break tag (second to last line of code) with a tag that will provide spacing between a new name and zone.    does not work. Simple but tricky for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//Universal clock 2006
//Genuine code by Corneliu Lucian "KOR" Rusu mailto:corneliulucian(AROND)apropo.ro
var wd=['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
var D=[
['Bucharest',120,60],//city,standard time zone(minutes), DST(minutes)
['Madrid',60,60],
['New York',-300,60],
['Nairobi',180,0]
]
//add in the array your cities,STZ, DST
function calc(){
var spans=document.getElementById('zonediv').getElementsByTagName('span')
for(var i=0;i<D.length;i++){
var t=new Date();
t.setTime(t.getTime()+(t.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)+((D[i][1]+D[i][2])*60000));//the zone's time
var Dy=t.getFullYear();
var Dd=t.getDate()<10?'0'+t.getDate():t.getDate();
var Dm=t.getMonth()<10?'0'+(t.getMonth()+1):t.getMonth()+1;
var Dh=t.getHours()<10?'0'+t.getHours():t.getHours(); 
var Di=t.getMinutes()<10?'0'+t.getMinutes():t.getMinutes();
var Ds=t.getSeconds()<10?'0'+t.getSeconds():t.getSeconds();
var Dz=wd[t.getDay()];
spans[i].firstChild.data=Dh+':'+Di+':'+Ds+' - '+Dz+' '+Dd+'/'+Dm+'/'+Dy;
}
setTimeout('calc()',1000)
}
onload=function(){
var root = document.getElementById('zonediv');
for(var i=0;i<D.length;i++){
root.appendChild(document.createTextNode(D[i][0]+' '))
var sp= document.createElement('span');
sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
root.appendChild(sp);root.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
}
calc();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="zonediv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

`root.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))`

with something like

`root.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '))`

This would append a space instead of a `br` element :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I added a bar as well and it worked great. 

root.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' | '));